# Im encountering error in R while plotting raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling

Dear fellow programmers!
I am trying to plot raster using follow in R

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

rast <- raster("HARV_dsmCrop.tif")

rast <- as.data.frame(rast, xy=TRUE)
View(rast)

ggplot()+
  geom_raster(rast, aes(HARV_dsmCrop))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10))
```

The code is throwing following error and the ggplot() was working fine just couple of minutes ago

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have the `ggplot` syntax wrong. In `geom_raster` the first argument should be the aesthetic mapping, whereas you have passed the data first. This is in contrast to the actual call to `ggplot`, where the data should be first.

Also, your call to `as.data.frame` means that your data is stored in three columns - an x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate and a value. These all need to be mapped to the appropriate aesthetic.

Obviously, we do not have your actual TIFF, so here is the code on an example tif which should also work for you:

```r
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

rast <- raster(path.expand("~/example.tif"))

rast <- as.data.frame(rast, xy = TRUE)

names(rast)[3] <- "Value"

ggplot(rast, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: oh yeah, I missed to define x and y in aesthetics. Thanks for your help buddy, you helped.